# View Centreon graph data

Tags: nagios, centreon

Is there a way to view the data that Centreon uses to build graphs, from within the Centreon web interface?

We have some gaps in some of our graphs, and I would like to see if it is a problem with the data being returned from the NRPE plugins.

I have seen the Monitoring>Event Logs section, but I can't get that to show the returned string and status for each call to a particular plugin, which is what I'd like. Is there a hidden function to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You've got the lastest result from each call in the service detail. Takine any service in any status, if you click on the service name from the monitoring view you get the detail where you could find latest check results.

For example:

```
Service Status  OK
Status information  
Disk OK - / TOTAL: 19.686GB USED: 5.418GB (27%) FREE: 14.268GB (73%)
Performance Data    size=21137846272B used=5817847808B;16910277017;19024061644;0;21137846272
Current Attempt     1 / 3
State Type  HARD
Last Check Type     Active
Last Check  2011/05/18 - 13:59:24
Next Scheduled Active Check     2011/05/18 - 14:59:24
Latency     0.86 seconds
...
```

Here the performance data is: `Performance Data     size=21137846272B used=5817847808B;16910277017;19024061644;0;21137846272`. It's in fact the last part returned in the check output (after the pipe).

To check how centreon handle that 'perfdata' you should Go to `administration>Options>Centstorage>Manage`, Here you can see for each service/host which metrics are extracted from the performance data string.

To get these metrics on a graph check that you've got it on `Views>Graphs>Curves`. You can easily create a new ones (with maybe not enought options, but for simple metrics it will be enough).